# 'Expected Idenfitier but got Public'

Tags: solidity, struct, error

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;


Books[] public individual_book;


struct Books {
    string author;
    string title;

}

function add_books(  string  _author,  string  _title) public  {
        individual_book.push(Books(_author, _title));

 }
```

the public keywords is in the right position so I am not sure why i am getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure, you are not forgetting the `contract` definition, are you?

Comment: oh wait, i did...